# Scrape inside link of homepage by logging into the homepage

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I will make this simple. I have a login page. I login. I see the homepage. The homepage has two links. I want to open these two links. Each link has two data. I just want four data from two links which are on the homepage that also comes after logging in. I can **scrape** upto the link step. I can **scrape** link but not the data inside the link. How do I do that? Thanks

My scrapy code: P.S i just did it on my own intuition, i don't know if it's possible.

```
import scrapy




class ClassroomSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'classroom'
    start_urls =['http://classroom.dwit.edu.np/login/index.php'] 
    login_url = 'http://classroom.dwit.edu.np/login/index.php'
    
    def parse(self, response): //code to login into the website
    
        data = {
            'username': mynameisaj
            'password': somerandomvalue
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.login_url,formdata = data, callback = self.parse_quotes)
        
    def parse_quotes(self,response):
        Link =  response.xpath('//*[@class="event"]/a/@href').extract()      //link in the homepage
        
        for item in zip(Link):
            scraped_info = {
                'Link':item[0],

            }
            yield scraped_info
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="event"]/a/@href').extract()  // link in the homepage
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse_data)
            
    def parse_data(self,response):
        Data = response.xpath('//*[@class="no-overflow"]/p/text()').extract() //data inside the link  in the homepage
        
        for item in zip(Data): 
            scraped_info1 = {
                'Data':item[0],
            }
            yield scraped_info1
```

**UPDATE**

The html element is :

```
<div id="intro" class="box generalbox boxaligncenter"><div class="no-overflow"><p>1) Write a program to print the area and perimeter of a triangle having sides of 3, 4 and 5 units by creating a class named 'Triangle' without any parameter in its constructor.</p>
<p><br>2) Write a program that would print the information (name, year of joining, salary, address) of three employees by creating a class named 'Employee'. <br>Create properties as needed for Employee class and set values to those properties using constructor with arguments.</p>
<p>The output should be as follows:</p>
<table border="0" style="width: 348px; height: 43px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong><span data-mce-mark="1">Name</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span data-mce-mark="1">Year of joining</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span data-mce-mark="1">Address</span></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span data-mce-mark="1">Robert</span></td>
<td><span data-mce-mark="1">1994</span></td>
<td><span data-mce-mark="1">64C- WallsStreet</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span data-mce-mark="1">Sam</span></td>
<td><span data-mce-mark="1">2000</span></td>
<td>Kathmandu</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<p>3) Create a class 'Degree' having a method 'getDegree' that prints "I got a degree". It has two subclasses namely 'Undergraduate' and 'Postgraduate' each having a method with the same name that prints "I am an Undergraduate" and "I am a Postgraduate" respectively. Call the method by creating an object of each of the three classes.</p>
<p>Note: Use separate class with main method</p></div></div>
```

All it **scraped** was the last p element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **combined** output for your two links you need to use `request.meta` (not tested):

```
def parse_quotes(self,response):

    # first you need to get ALL links you want to process
    your_links =  response.xpath('//*[@class="event"]/a/@href').extract()

    first_link = your_links.pop(0)

    # and start processing from the very first link
    yield scrapy.Request(url = first_link, callback = self.parse_data, meta={"links": your_links})

def parse_data(self,response):

    item = {}

    # If we already have some Item data we need to continue with it
    if "item" in response.meta:
        item = response.meta["item"]

    # Below you need to parse HTML and update your Item
    Data = response.xpath('//*[@class="no-overflow"]/p/text()').extract()

    for item in zip(Data): 
        item = {
            'Data':item[0],
        }

    # Now we need to check if we need to process other Links
    if len(response.meta["links"]) > 0:
        next_link_url  = response.meta["links"].pop(0)
        yield scrapy.Request(url = next_link_url, callback = self.parse_data, meta={"links": response.meta["links"], "item": item})
    else:

        # No more links to process, just save output
        yield item
```

Comment: yield scrapy.Request(url = next_link_url, callback = self.parse_data, meta={"links": your_links, "item": item})
NameError: name 'your_links' is not defined

Comment: how to i pass your_links to parse_data function?

Comment: i mistakley updated in your comment. would you please see my updated question? it only scraps last element of one link

Comment: @UchihaAJ Obviously I can't help you because I don't know what do you want to parse from above fragment.

Comment: every /text() from every tag.

Comment: Just use this XPath `//text()`

Comment: you mean something like: `Data = response.xpath('//*[@class="no-overflow"]//text()').extract() ?`